# trying to set the value of field name but that field name is stored in some string

Tags: apex, trigger, list

i am trying to set the value of field name but that field name is stored in some string, in Line 9, do any of you have any idea how can we achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `SObject.put` method (rather than `SObject.get`).

```
c.put(targetField, someValue);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please note in the future you should always post your code as *text*. Sharing as image is extremely poor for accessibility and will lower you chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!